# SQL getting distinct, max, and id

Tags: sql, postgresql, max, distinct

I have a table called versions and I am trying to get the id, the body, and the highest version.  I am using Postgres

When I use

```
SELECT DISTINCT(body), MAX(version) FROM versions
WHERE body = 'Maintain records of all disclosures'
GROUP BY body
```

I get
[image]

When I try to add id

```
SELECT DISTINCT(body), MAX(version), id  FROM versions
WHERE body = 'Maintain records of all disclosures'
GROUP BY body, id
```

I get

[image]

What do I need to change so I am only getting the id where max is the highest?

Comment: Could you please specify database you use. For example, in SQL Server you can SELECT TOP 1 * FROM TABLE ORDER BY VERSION DESC

Comment: @Sergey I updated the post.  I am using Postgres

Comment: Have you tried SELECT body,version, id from  versions
WHERE body = 'Maintain records of all disclosures' order by version desc limit 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
SELECT body, version, id 
FROM versions 
WHERE version = (
 SELECT MAX(version) 
  FROM versions 
  WHERE body = 'Maintain records of all disclosures') 
AND body = 'Maintain records of all disclosures'
```

Answer (score 0):

- using windows functions to get max
  https://www.sqlshack.com/use-window-functions-sql-server/
- using row number to remove dupes

https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/eliminating-duplicate-rows-using-the-partition-by-clause

```
WITH DATA AS (

SELECT BODY, 
       ID,
       MAX(version) OVER(PARITION BY BODY ORDER BY ID) AS MAX_VERSION,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY BODY ORDER BY ID) AS ROW_NUM

FROM versions
WHERE body = 'Maintain records of all disclosures'

)

SELECT 
*
FROM DATA
WHERE ROW_NUM = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want `distinct on`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (v.body), v.*
FROM versions v
WHERE v.body = 'Maintain records of all disclosures'
ORDER BY body, version DESC;
```

However, with only one row desired in the result set, `LIMIT` is sufficient:

```
SELECT v.*
FROM versions v
WHERE v.body = 'Maintain records of all disclosures'
ORDER BY body, version DESC
LIMIT 1;
```